# PostgreSQL функиця со значением по умолчанию

Tags: postgresql

Как реализовать следующее, нужен тригер/функция который бы автоматически генерировал такого рода номер (А1, А2 и.т.д)при добавлении записи в таблицу (поесть в определенное поле вставлял значение по умолчанию)
при этом, каждый день обнулялись бы значения., то-есть после 00.01 (ну или изменения даты) счетчик бы опять стал на A1

Comment: фиксировать дату и текущее значение в отдельной таблице. Вообще хотелось бы узнать зачем это надо, может есть другие, более простые способы решения.

Comment: пишу электронную очередь... возможно вы правы и кто подскажет более правильный подход.

Comment: У вас отдельные очереди ожидаются (там "A001", "B001") ?

Comment: да отдельные...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для хранения текущего номера очереди предлагаю создать отдельную таблицу с такой структурой:

```
create table queue(
 type char(1) not null,                   -- Тип очереди "A", "B", ...
 date date not null default current_date, -- Дата
 current int not null default 1,          -- Текущий номер
 primary key(type, date)
);
```

Тогда получить новый номер из заданной очереди можно следующим запросом:

```
insert into queue(type) values('A')
 on conflict(type, date)
 do update set current=queue.current+1
 returning current
```

Данный запрос можете завернуть в функцию, которая на вход получает только тип очереди. Или использовать непосредственно в триггере основной таблицы, где номера будут использоваться. Что бы получать номера уже с буквой и так их и хранить в целевой таблице можно написать `returning type||current`.

Comment: спасибо завтра попробую